How reduce space between items in a list and space between text and list
So for one of my uni projects, I have to rewrite an old book of LIE ALGEBRAS into LaTeX code. I'm currently working on a paragraph with lists, but I don't know how to reduce the space between the items in my list, or the space between my text and the list. The first picture is what it's supposed to look like, and the second picture is what I have.
This is my code for this part:
    \raggedright into $\mathfrak{M}$ mapping $(x,a), x \in \mathfrak{M}, a \in \mathfrak{U}$, into an element \(xa \in \mathfrak{M}\) such 

that
\setlist{nolistsep}
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
    \item
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \((x_1 + x_2)a = x_1a + x_2a,\)
            \columnbreak
             \(x(a_1 + a_2) = xa_1 + xa_2,\)
        \end{multicols}
    \item
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \(\alpha (xa) = (\alpha x)a = x(\alpha a),\)
            \columnbreak
             \(a \in \Phi, \quad\)            % \quad nodig omdat de tweede kolom anders niet werkt
        \end{multicols}
    \item
        \(x(ab) = (xa)b\).
\end{enumerate}
If $a \rightarrow A$ is a representation of $\mathfrak{U}$, then the representation space $\mathfrak{M}$ 

can be made into a right $\mathfrak{U}$-module by defining \(xa \equiv xA\) Thus we 

will have 
\setlist{nolistsep}
\begin{align*}
(x_1 + x_2)a &= (x_1 + x_2)A = x_1A + x_2A = x_1a + x_2a \\
x(a_1 + a_2) &= x(A_1 + A_2) = xA_1 + xA_2 = xa_1 + xa_2 \\
\alpha (xa) &= \alpha (xA) = (\alpha x)A = (\alpha x)a \\
\alpha (xA) &= x(\alpha A) = x(\alpha a) \\
x(ab) &= x(AB) = (xA)B = (xa)b . \\
\end{align*}




Welcome to TeX.SE.

Which document class do you employ? Which font size? Are any packages other than multicol, amsmath, amssymb and enumitem needed to compile your document?

Assuming 10pt is the main font size, you could run \usepackage[textwidth=10.5cm]{geometry} in the preamble to get the approximately correct line width, and you wouldn't have impose \raggedright and/or manually break lines.

Not sure what multicol is for: it just makes the thing difficult to read.
Also \raggedright and using blank lines for new lines doesn't seem the best input style.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent % <-- just to emulate continuing text
into \(\mathfrak{M}\) mapping \((x,a)\), \(x \in \mathfrak{M}\), 
\(a \in \mathfrak{A}\), into an element \(xa \in \mathfrak{M}\) 
such that
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
  \item \((x_1 + x_2)a = x_1a + x_2a\),\qquad \(x(a_1 + a_2) = xa_1 + xa_2\),
  \item \(\alpha (xa) = (\alpha x)a = x(\alpha a)\), \(a \in \Phi\),
  \item \(x(ab) = (xa)b\).
\end{enumerate}
If $a \rightarrow A$ is a representation of $\mathfrak{A}$, then the 
representation space $\mathfrak{M}$ can be made into a right 
$\mathfrak{A}$\nobreakdash-module by defining \(xa \equiv xA\). Thus we 
will have 
\begin{align*}
(x_1 + x_2)a &= (x_1 + x_2)A = x_1A + x_2A = x_1a + x_2a \\
x(a_1 + a_2) &= x(A_1 + A_2) = xA_1 + xA_2 = xa_1 + xa_2 \\
\alpha (xa) &= \alpha (xA) = (\alpha x)A = (\alpha x)a \\
\alpha (xA) &= x(\alpha A) = x(\alpha a) \\
x(ab) &= x(AB) = (xA)B = (xa)b .
\end{align*}

\end{document}

Points to note:

nosep removes the space around the enumerate and also the spaces between items;
there should never be a trailing \\ in align and friends;
the first line contains four formulas and not two as you wrote;
punctuation should go outside inline formulas;
the original has a Fraktur A, not U (thanks to Mico for noting).



+1. I think that all instances of \mathfrak{U} should actually be \mathfrak{A}.

@Mico Yes! Fixed and added a point to note.
